# Deleting menus and menu items

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want delete menu and its links during UN install. how do i do that. i added menu like this,

my_custom_menu.install

```
function my_custom_menu_install() {
  $t = get_t();
  $menu = array(
    'menu_name' => 'custom-menu',
    'title' => $t('My custom menu'),
    'description' => $t('The <em>Custom</em> menu contains links for testing only.'),
  );
  menu_save($menu);
}
function my_custom_menu_uninstall() {
    // i want to delete menu from here during uninstall.
}
```

Any body help me?

Answer (score 1):

To delete a custom menu and all its links, use [menu_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_delete/7).

```
function my_custom_menu_uninstall() {
    menu_delete(menu_load('custom-menu'));
}
```